# Should I Use Schema.Types.ObjectId or Schema.ObjectId When Defining a Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

It seems like defining my Schema this way:

```
var PossessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  thing: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Thing"}
});
```

or this way:

```
var PossessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  thing: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Thing"}
});
```

Both work. I see that the mongoose guide uses Schema.Types.ObjectId

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

But I'm confused that both work.

Which one should be used for the Schema? And what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't matter. Both is exactly the same. If you actually `console.log(mongoose.Schema);` you can see that both `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId` and `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` refer to the exact same thing.

```
{ [Function: Schema]
  reserved: { 
    _posts: 1,
    _pres: 1,
    validate: 1,
    toObject: 1,
    set: 1,
    schema: 1,
    save: 1,
    modelName: 1,
    get: 1,
    isNew: 1,
    isModified: 1,
    init: 1,
    errors: 1,
    db: 1,
    collection: 1,
    once: 1,
    on: 1,
    emit: 1 
  },
  interpretAsType: [Function],
  Types: { 
    String: { [Function: SchemaString] schemaName: 'String' },
    Number: { [Function: SchemaNumber] schemaName: 'Number' },
    Boolean: { [Function: SchemaBoolean] schemaName: 'Boolean', '$conditionalHandlers': [Object] },
    DocumentArray: { [Function: DocumentArray] schemaName: 'DocumentArray' },
     Embedded: [Function: Embedded],
    Array: { [Function: SchemaArray] schemaName: 'Array' },
    Buffer: { [Function: SchemaBuffer] schemaName: 'Buffer' },
    Date: { [Function: SchemaDate] schemaName: 'Date' },
    ObjectId: { [Function: ObjectId] schemaName: 'ObjectId' },
    Mixed: { [Function: Mixed] schemaName: 'Mixed' },
    Oid: { [Function: ObjectId] schemaName: 'ObjectId' },
    Object: { [Function: Mixed] schemaName: 'Mixed' },
    Bool: { [Function: SchemaBoolean] schemaName: 'Boolean', '$conditionalHandlers': [Object] } 
  },
  ObjectId: { [Function: ObjectId] schemaName: 'ObjectId' } 
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) says: "To specify a type of ObjectId, use Schema.Types.ObjectId in your declaration."... "or just Schema.ObjectId for backwards compatibility with v2".

So I use "Schema.Types.ObjectId".

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old topic but I ran into some trouble in this area recently, so here's what I found in case anyone else's banging their heads against the wall:

Whenever you use a reference in your schema to an ObjectId, you MUST use mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId.

mongoose.Types.ObjectId should be used solely for its constructor when building new objectIds from a string hex or, as it's probably the most common use case, to validate a string as an ObjectId hex, say:

```
try {
  let oid = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('XXXXXXXXX')
} catch (e) {
  console.error('not a valid ObjectId hex string ==> ', e)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much of a difference, but they are available for separate uses.

> Schemas should always use `mongoose.Schema.Types`.
>
> `mongoose.Types` are the object you work with within a mongoose
>   document. These are special array subclasses, buffer subclasses, etc
>   that we've hooked into or created special to ease updates and track
>   changes.

*Source: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1671*