# What does it mean in VSCode if a module is green and if you access an object with it via dot notation and the object is grey and not green?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: photo showing different colors on vscode]When I do

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

The `mongoose` immediately after const is green.

When I do `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` the the whole code, `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` is green.

But when I do `mongoose.ObjectId` the `mongoose` is green but the `objectId` is not. What does this mean?(see above image for photo of the same)

Comment: why don't you use the screen dump tool of the OS/Desktop, This is unreadable stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current theme you're using *(Dark+)*  highlights ***classes***, ***modules***, ***namespaces*** in green.
The reason for `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` being green is because all of the text are either a module or a namespace.
The reason for `mongoose` in  `mongoose.ObjectId`  being green and `ObjectId` being not, is becuase `mongoose` is a ***module*** but the `ObjectId` in this scenario is not.

You can find the difference between `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` and `mongoose.ObjectId` in this [StackOverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997636/should-i-use-schema-types-objectid-or-schema-objectid-when-defining-a-mongoose-s)