# What do the icons and their colors in VSCode suggestion pop up mean?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: photo of vscode suggestion popup]

What do the icons and their colors before the words in the suggestion popup mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons indicate what type of item is the pop up suggesting. *(e.g. Method, Class, Property)*

- The icon on the *Schema* indicates that the following item is a **class**.
- The icon on the *SchemaTypes* indicates that the following item is a **property**
- The icon on the *Types* indicates that the following item is a **module**.
- The icon on the *connect* indicates that the following item is a **method**.

**You can find more information about these icons in the [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions)**

Comment: Hey, kindly check my [other question still on VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70849540/9953550). Thanks.